# Counting the number of times a character appears in a string in c programming?

Tags: c, char, c-strings

The for loop below continues until the end of the string, while the if branch checks to see how many times the character 'u' appears in the string, "yuzuf Oztuk", which is 3 times. Meanwhile, the variable count counts the number of u's in the string. When i compile the code, I get 15 for the number of times u appears in the string, which is wrong.

```
int numTimesAppears(char* mystring, char ch)
{
    int i;
    int count;
    for(i = 0; mystring[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {
        if (mystring[i] == ch)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `int count;` --> `int count = 0;`

Comment: Thank You, I just compiled it and it gave me the correct answer.

Comment: use of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior

Comment: @user24741  It is better to use standard C function strchr instead of a loop. Take into account that the first parameter should be specified like const char* mystring

Answer (score 2):

> I get 15 for the number of times u appears in the string, which is wrong.

1. Key issue: Code needs to initialize the value of `count`. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085187/counting-the-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-a-string-in-c-programming#comment79132503_46085187)

   ```
   // int count;
   int count = 0;
   ```
2. Corner case: As the *null character* is in the string, a result of 1 "for number of times a character appears in a string" would be expected for any `numTimesAppears(some_string, '\0')`.  A `do` loop fixes that.  A similar standard library function is `strchr()`, which looks for the first match and considers the *null character* part of the search-able *string*:  "... terminating null character is considered to be part of the string."  As with all corner cases, various results could be inferred - best to document the coding goal in this case.

   ```
   i = 0;
   do {
     if (mystring[i] == ch) {
       count++;
     }
   } while (mystring[i++]);
   ```
3. As the function does not modify the inspected string, making it `const` increases the function's applicability and perhaps performance. [@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085187/counting-the-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-a-string-in-c-programming/46085480#comment79132769_46085187)
4. Array indexing best uses `size_t` rather than `int`.  `int` may be too narrow.

   ```
   size_t numTimesAppears(const char* mystring, char ch) {
     size_t count = 0;
     size_t i = 0;
     do {
       if (mystring[i] == ch) {
         count++;
       }
     } while (mystring[i++]);
     return count;
   }
   ```

Comment: 2 is wrong. A string does not "contain" the NUL character. The fact that a NUL is used to implement a C string does not mean it contains the NUL. If it helps to think about this, the number of characters contained by a string is given by `strlen()`, and `strlen()` does not include the NUL in its count. `numTimesAppears(anyString, '\0')` should always return `0`.

Comment: @KevinBallard Concerning ["A string does not "contain" the NUL character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085187/counting-the-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-a-string-in-c-programming/46085480?noredirect=1#comment79133256_46085480), the C spec defines _string_ as "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and **including the first null
character**."  Perhaps C spec is amiss? A number of standard lib functions explicitly don't count the _null character_, & others explicitly do. IAC,I think we agree the function should be documented per this case.

Comment: 4. is a bit dicey. It's width is implementation defined (6.5.3.4), and is not recommended to have a conversion rank greater than *signed long int* (7.1.9) and is only guaranteed to be larger than `65535` (7.20.3) -- though any compiler I've seen at least provides a range over the positive values of `int`, and Gnu does provide a range over the positive values of `long int`. So it is another wonderful bit of implementation defined soup....

Comment: @chux You're confusing implementation details with semantics. A C string's implementation is such that the in-memory representation contains a NUL. A C string's semantics are such that a C string can never contain a NUL (because attempting to put one in the C string instead just truncates the string).

Comment: @KevinBallard No confusion on my part.  A C _string_ contains the _null character_ - that is the implementation details and semantics specified by C standard library. That is the reference I am using.  Your assertion that _string_ does not contain a _null character_ is not yet backed by a reference.   In the end - it is clear we both  understand C _string_, yet use a different way of describing them.  My rational for `numTimesAppears(s, '\0') ` matches `strchr(s, '\0')` which "... terminating null character is considered to be part of the string."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The range of `size_t` and `int` are _both_ implementation defined.  The range of `size_t` matches the range of possible array indexes  of `mystring[i]` and the range of possible results of  `numTimesAppears()`.  `int` matches neither.   BTW 7.1.9 appears to be C11 §7.19 4

Comment: @chux agreed, the 7.1.9 -> 7.19.4 (fat fingers...)